# How can I delete shiny apps which are not working, from my account(from shiny server)?

Tags: shiny, shiny-server

As I deploy the app, there remain some anomalies in the application, so I want to delete them from my account. I tried but didn't find any option to do it. Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use terminateApp("") as you used deployApp("appname") after filling token information from shiny.io.

Answer (score 1):

Didn't work. I can't delete archived app.

Error:

```
Waiting for task: 1103099358
  error: Deleting images
Error: Unhandled Exception: object list can't be used in 'await' expression
```

Comment: I am having the same Error and have tried multiple times to restore/archive/delete to no avail.

Comment: So. After two days I did it. I don't know, what was wrong.

Comment: Same here, it worked today. I'm assuming it was a shinyapps friday evening quirk?

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

1. log in to your account on [shinyapps.io](https://www.shinyapps.io/admin/#/login),
2. click on `Applications` button in menu,
3. choose an app you want to delete and click on `Archive Application` button,
4. finally, you can delete the app by clicking on `Delete Application` button (trash bin icon).